# GitLab CI configuration is invalid: stages config should be an array of strings

Tags: gitlab-ci

I getting an error on stages on that pipeline.

GitLab CI configuration is invalid: stages config should be an array of strings.

```
stages:
   -test
   -run

image: python:latest

variables:
 PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
 paths:
   - .cache/pip
   - venv/

test-asamasi:
   stage: test
   script:
       - python --version 
       - pip install virtualenv
       - virtualenv venv
       - source venv/bin/activate
       - python sslkontrol.py test

calistirma:
   stage: run
   script: 
       - python sslkontrol.py
```

Comment: add a space after `-` character in line 2 and 3

Comment: You could use CI Lint always to make sure that your config is proper or not before committing.  Excerpt from Gitlab Help . If you want to test the validity of your GitLab CI/CD configuration before committing
the changes, you can use the CI Lint tool. This tool checks for syntax and logical
errors by default, and can simulate pipeline creation to try to find more complicated
issues as well.
To access the CI Lint tool, navigate to CI/CD > Pipelines or CI/CD > Jobs
in your project and click CI lint.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your pipeline file above and I was able to get it working by adding space between `-` character and stage name(e.g - test) as shown below:

```
stages:
   - test
   - run

image: python:latest

variables:
 PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
 paths:
   - .cache/pip
   - venv/

test-asamasi:
   stage: test
   script:
       - python --version 
       - pip install virtualenv
       - virtualenv venv
       - source venv/bin/activate
       - python sslkontrol.py test

calistirma:
   stage: run
   script: 
       - python sslkontrol.py
```

**Recommendations**

1. Now its easier to visualize, lint/validate your gitlab pipeline(e.g ) from within Gitlab console using this instructions [Validate GitLab CI/CD configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html)

Answer (score 0):

On small mistake on the stages, you need to add an extra space between the **-** and **test**

[image: image here]

Comment: don't post images as answers please